# How to pass AWS credential when building Docker image in Jenkins?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, aws-cdk

Hi I am working in jenkins to build my AWS CDK project. I have created my docker file as below.

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10
ENV CDK_VERSION='1.14.0'

RUN mkdir /cdk

COPY ./requirements.txt /cdk/
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY ./aws /cdk/
WORKDIR /cdk

RUN apk -uv add --no-cache groff jq less
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN npm install -g aws-cdk
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN ls -la
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

RUN cdk synth
RUN cdk deploy
```

In jenkins I am building this Docker image as below.

```
 stages {
     stage('Dev Code Deploy') {
      when {
        expression {
          return BRANCH_NAME = 'Develop'
        }
      }
      agent {
        dockerfile {
          additionalBuildArgs "--build-arg 'http_proxy=${env.http_proxy}' --build-arg 'https_proxy=${env.https_proxy}'"
          filename 'Dockerfile'
          args '-u root:root'
        }
      }
```

In the above code I am not supplying AWS credentials So when cdk synth is executed I get error `Need to perform AWS calls for account 1234567 but no credentials found. Tried: default credentials.`

In jenkins I have my AWS credentials and I can access this like

```
 steps {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: "${env.PROJECT_ID}-aws-${env.ENVIRONMENT}"]]) {
           sh 'ls -la'
           sh "bash ./scripts/build.sh"
        }
      }
```

But how can I pass these credentialsId when building docker image. Can someone help me to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that you should NOT store credentials in Docker image, since everybody can get them there. Credentials are usually passed as environment variables to Docker containers.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to pass credentials like below.

```
steps {
        script {
          node {
            checkout scm
              withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: "${env.PROJECT_ID}-aws-${CFN_ENVIRONMENT}"]]) {
                abc = docker.build('cdkimage', "--build-arg http_proxy=${env.http_proxy} --build-arg https_proxy=${env.https_proxy} .")
                abc.inside{
                sh 'ls -la'
                sh "bash ./scripts/build.sh"
              }
        }
        }
      }
```

I have added below code in build.sh

```
cdk synth
cdk deploy
```

Comment: What's your cdkimage content? (assuming this a dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

You should install  the "Amazon ECR" plugin and restart Jenkins

Fulfil the plugin with your credential. And specify in pipeline

All documentation you can find here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+ECR

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to push image to ecr

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jenkins pipeline, maybe you can try [withAWS](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#withaws-set-aws-settings-for-nested-block) step.

This should provide a way to access Jenkins aws credential, then pass the credential as docker environment while running docker container.

ref:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your access key id
2. Add the section withCredentials to create the variables on that environment.

```
    stage("Run process on image") {
        steps {
            withCredentials([aws(credentialsId: 'awscredentialId', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', secretKeyVarible: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]) {
                sh "docker-compose run -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY " #complete the variables and command to execute and pass to docker
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your comment proved useful for me, but I found there's a typo in your aws arguments. It reads secretKeyVarible instead of secretKeyVariable. Also, Jenkins now by default warns about secret substitution in sh commands. Best is to change this line to use single quotes instead. More about this here: https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation

Comment: i get an "unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e".  does not look like docker-compose supports such an arg